# What else do I need to call my compound control?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created a compound control with the following:

**Java**

```
public class QuantityBox extends LinearLayout 
{
    private TextView partNmbr;
    private Button decrease;
    private Button increase;
    private EditText quantity;
    private int qty;

    public QuantityBox(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        // load views
        loadViews();
    }

    /**
     * This constructor is necessary in order to use this compound
     * control in an XML layout.
     * @param context Application context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public QuantityBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        // inflate the view we created
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.quantity_box, this);

        // load views
        loadViews();
    }

    /**
     * Load the views created from the constructor
     */
    private void loadViews()
    {
        this.qty = 1;

        partNmbr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPartNmbr);
        decrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrease);
        increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIncrease);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQty);

        // set initial text
        quantity.setText(this.qty);

        decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // decrease quantity
                qty--;

                // update view
                quantity.setText(qty);
            }

        });

        increase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // increase quantity
                qty++;

                // update view
                quantity.setText(qty);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPartNmbr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDecrease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="-"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etQty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIncrease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="+"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I trying to create it here, programmatic-ally:

```
    public class CustomHeaderActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.custom_title_bar);

            QuantityBox qb = new QuantityBox(this);
        }
}
```

Why isn't this working? Am I missing a step? (`NullPointerException` is thrown.)

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace available?

Comment: the logcat shows a nullpointer on the onCreate -- on the QuantityBox

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped into the QuantityBox constructor code and loadviews method to see exactly what is null? It could be that your context is null. Try passing getApplicationContext() or CustomHeaderActivity.this (or may be CustomHeaderActivity.class - I can't remember).

Comment: Unrelated, but heh: `// load views loadViews();` Thank goodness for comments!

Answer (score 0):

The widgets will not be there by the time you call `loadViews()`. Wait for that until `onFinishInflate()`.

Comment: What do you mean? Do I need to implement something else for `onFinishInflate()`?

Comment: Why one cannot reference inflated views right after `inflater.inflate()` but should wait for `onFinishInflate()`? According to source it is the `LayoutInflater` which calls `onFinishInflate()` when the view hierarchy is created. However, as I understand the android source, these callbacks are done before the `inflate` method ends, so I'm bit confused whether the usage of `onFinishInflate()` in this situation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You never inflate your view in the constructor that only takes the Context argument, meaning quantity.setText(...); will throw a NPE because quantity wasn't found in findViewById(...);